# Adding aspectJ language to define joinpoints

Tags: java, maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'd like to define aspectj joinpoints not using annotations and string constants like this:

```
@Before("execution(* my.class.getText(..))")
```

but using aspecj language, like in this example:

```
pointcut myMethod(): myClass() && execution(* *(..));
```

or

```
before (): getText() {
    Trace.traceEntry("" + thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature());
}
```

Is there any good examples of how to add aspectj to the project to make maven compile this language properly and how to re-write @Before, @Around etc. annotations in aspecj language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some resources:

- the [AspectJ homepage](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) including developer tutorials, also showing you how to use the [AspectJ compiler (Ajc)](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ajc-ref.html) from the command line,
- information about [AspectJ Development Tools (AJDT)](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/) for Eclipse (but there is also an AspectJ integration into IntelliJ IDEA if you prefer that),
- a link to the [AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) which enables you to easily compile your Maven project including aspects.

Here on Stack Overflow, I have also answered many questions about how to configure AspectJ Maven Plugin, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25480409/1082681).