# maven plugin execution issue

Tags: maven, aspectj

I am using aspectj in a project. when i add the aspectj-maven-plugin to the build, the aspects are woven in and things work as expected. however, i get an error in the POM saying that the plugin execution is not covered by lifecycle configuration.

from what i've read in other problems, it says the solution is to simply wrap the plugin in a pluginManagement tag. that does seem to get rid of the error, however, when i do a `mvn clean install`, the aspectj plugin no longer runs. any idea on how to solve that problem?

Comment: can you post your code please? could this be the same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474505/aspectj-in-maven-project-not-working-weaving/25480409

Comment: This sounds like a message from inside of Eclipse ?

Comment: @khmarbaise correct, this is an error message in eclipse. the project still builds fine, though

Comment: Ok that's what I expected. That means the message is not an issue etc. or in contradiction as you wrote no error ...This is a WARNING in Eclipse......